# How WordPress manages nested dropdown?

Tags: pages, dropdown, hierarchical

I made a hierarchical CPT, so it involves various depths. I need to make a dropdown, and I found [`wp_dropdown_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages). But for some reasons, at last I made my own dropdown querying [`get_pages()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) and using `foreach` loop.

But then I see that, using `wp_dropdown_pages()` I can have a nice, nested dropdown. I inspected the dropdown, and found there are classes for every depth, like `level-0`, `level-1` etc. But inspecting all the way I couldn't find any CSS for those classes. No such CSS declaration in WordPress either.
It became a mystery to me!! :o

[image: nested dropdown in WordPress]

How actually WordPress manages nested dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `<option>` field doesn't work with any CSS. So WordPress Developers/Designers did a simple yet nice trick for the nesting layout for `<option>` fields.

[image: Level pads]

Actually in your inspection you missed something there:

```
<select name="page_id" id="page_id">
    <option value="1" class="level-0">Level 0</option>
    <option value="2" class="level-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Level 1</option>
    <option value="3" class="level-1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Level 1</option>
    <option value="4" class="level-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Level 2</option>
    <option value="5" class="level-3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Level 3</option>
    <option value="6" class="level-2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Level 2</option>
    <option value="7" class="level-3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Level 3</option>
</select>
```

Have you noted the population of `&nbsp;` (HTML special character for spaces) there?

That is what creating the nesting look.

### Let's get the hand dirty

- In WordPress `wp-includes/` folder, open the file `post-template.php`.
- Now find `wp_dropdown_pages(`, so that you can find the function showing the dropdown <sup>(Line #1016 in WP 4.3.1)</sup>
- In that function you will see another function is functioning there: `walk_page_dropdown_tree(`, search for  that one. <sup>(Line #1309 in WP 4.3.1)</sup>
- In that function you will see a Walker Class is functioning there, `Walker_PageDropdown`, find that class now. <sup>(Line #1471 in WP 4.3.1)</sup>
- In that class you will see a function named `start_el`, and within that function actually the trick is running.

Have you noticed that `$pad` variable there?

```
$pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);
```

Passing the `$depth` of the page, this `str_repeat()` is actually populating the spaces (`&nbsp;`) there. [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) is a PHP function that repeats a string for specified times. And it's working simply multiplying `&nbsp;` 3 times to the `$depth`. And that's the trick.

### Let's do it

Now let us implement the similar thing in your case:

```
$_pages = get_pages( array( 'post_type'=> 'your_hierachical_cpt' ) );
<select name="my_field" id="my-field">
    <?php foreach ($_pages as $_page) {
        $depth = count( get_post_ancestors( $_page->ID ) ); //page_depth
        $pad = str_repeat('&nbsp;', $depth * 3);
        echo '<option value="'. $_page->ID .'" class="level-'. $depth .'">'. $pad . $_page->post_title .'</option>';
    } ?>
</select>
```

We're having all the pages in `$_pages`, having each of their depth in `$depth`, and then following that simple trick, in `$pad`. And when showing `<option>`s, we are showing the `$depth` classes, and adding the `$pad` variable just before options' texts.

*Yay!* :D